# How can i add values to array (with post) on function?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add values to php array with $_post  sentence ,using a function.But when i add a value, this replaces the element [0] of the array without increasing the length of it, what am I doing wrong ?.I used 'serialize' and 'unserialize' to fix this, since without functions it works, but now not.

```
<?php

global $array;
$array = array();

$long = count($array);
$array = unserialize($_POST["array"]);

function add($value){

     $array[] =  $value ;

     return $array;

}

if (isset($_POST["Add"])){
    $array =  add($_POST['valor']);
     if(count($array)>0)
     {  
      print_r(array_values($array));
     }    
}
?>


<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="array" value='<?php echo serialize($array);?>'>
    Add value: <input type="text" name="valor" size="2"> 
    <input type="submit" name= "Add" value="Añadir">  
</form>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Like you did at the beginning of your file, you need `global $array;` in your function.

Comment: Solved! Thank you for reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be:

```
function add($value){
  global $array;
  $array[] =  $value;
  return $array;
}
```

This way you are using the `$array` you previously declared.

Initially, it would just create an empty array and add your value in the function, so it would always return one value.

Also, since `$array` is a global variable, you do not really need to return it from the function. You can use

```
function add($value){
  global $array;
  $array[] =  $value;
}
```

then just

```
add($_POST['valor']);
```

instead of

```
$array =  add($_POST['valor']);
```

Comment: 3 days breaking my mind for just one line of code ...Thank so much,dude! :D